# Displaying Instructions popups on first startup

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have an android App and I would like to instruct the user on the main features and where to go first when he first install and run the App.
I have around 5 popups.

Currently I have a code that shows popups that I have created with my layouts for each popup and I feel that it's the wrong way. Takes too much time and has no proper reuse of code.

Is there a known design pattern or conventional way that helps displaying these instructions popups?

Thanks!

Comment: you can refer these libraries for displaying instructions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298590/first-time-user-guide-through-android-library

Comment: Thanks @Rahul verma, I will give it a look and update here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using popups you can use App Introduction slides.

There are many libraries which you can directly use for this:

Check out this one: [App Intro](https://github.com/heinrichreimer/material-intro)

I'm currently using this : [App Intro 2](https://github.com/rubengees/introduction)

**To display it only once use this code in the Launcher activity on create**

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //  Initialize SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

            //  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true
            boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

            //  If the activity has never started before...
            if (isFirstStart) {

                //load the tutorial now
                loadTutorial();
                SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();
                e.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
                e.apply();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

**Now load tutorials: (This is how I'm using the second library)**

```
public void loadTutorial() {

    new IntroductionBuilder(this).withSlides(generateSlides()).introduceMyself();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Arahasya, I think this is what I'm looking for. I'm guessing the loadTutorial() method holds the screens logic itself? Is this logic management a part of the Infrastructure?

Comment: check my edited ans. Use the second link and follow the instructions. I've posted the link which I'm using.

Comment: The logic to run it only once is seperate from the library. According to this it will run it only the first time. But you can display it whenever you call loadTutorial(). You can set a button for it